# Image of centralizer under an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have a group isomorphism $\phi: G\rightarrow K$ between two finite groups and let $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Are there any known facts about the image of the centralizer $C_G(H)$ of $H$ in $G$ under $\phi$? 
Also, same question for the special case of $K=G$ i.e. when $\phi$ is an automorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Morally, you can view isomorphism as just relabeling the elements of a group without changing any structure. So the best we can hope to say is that $$\phi(C_G(H)) = C_K(\phi(H))$$

Edit: I realize now that "best we can hope to say" is a bit strange. Basically any structure you define in group theoretic terms will carry over precisely under isomorphism.

Comment: In the case of automorphism we don't have that the centralizer is preserved because not all subgroups are preserved right? i.e. we don't have $\phi(H)=H$ for all subgroups $H$

Comment: Yeah, $C_G(\phi(H)) \neq C_G(H)$ in general, but that's because you failed to relabel totally. The correct statement is $\phi(C_G(H)) = C_G(\phi(H))$, so "centralizer of image is image of centralizer". Unless you know $H$ is a characteristic subgroup i don't know how you  could hope to say more.